# How to disable cloudera parcels from automatically distributing to all hosts or is there a way to setup a repo for all hosts?

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-manager

I'm using Cloudera Manager 6.3.1 and have noticed that when I download parcels, they are automatically distributed to all hosts even though I do not need them in some all hosts.

So, the question is, is there a way to disable it? Or, can I create an internal repository which will be used by all hosts instead of replicating the parcels to each one of them?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to disable the parcel distribution on selected hosts. CM keeps up to date copy of parcels on all hosts it manages. Once activate, the parcel will be copied on all the hosts.

If there are parcels which are not in Activated status and you would like to make some space on agent hosts, from parcel page you can click drop down next to Parcel Name > Remove From Hosts. CM will delete the parcel from all the hosts in the cluster but will keep a copy at CM host parcel-repo directory so that you can again distribute it later.